Ear training - really struggling with intervals
My family is 75% professional musicians but I've had a scattered education.
I'm trying isolate what I'm missing and what exactly is the issue.
I can read basic sheet music, I can sing well, and I can follow familiar scales and intervals in situ and generally gather which note a phrase will extend to or end on, but anything else - I'm struggling to hear it. I've played piano, trumpet and sung, but always struggled with string instruments - I think keys help my brain essentially cheat the interval and lock in on the correct note.
I'm also able to 'cheat' accidentally and really easily by memorising patterns - which makes it a struggle to extrapolate to the general. Repetitive interval training exercises like '1,121,12321, 1x343x1, 1xx4xx1 just get coded in my brain as a song, it seems.
Any strategies? I'm struggling to make progress. I realise this issue has come up for me a lot in terms of when I was studying - I hit wrong notes a fair bit when I've failed to memorise the tricky intervals or spot it in sheet music or they're in isolation.
Are there strategies to hone in on this issue? Pure repetition isn't helping, neither are exercises with a strong memorisation component. Should I put more effort into memorising intervals from familiar songs? listening to multiple songs with those intervals to try to isolate it?

I think there is a problem to solve here, but I'm afraid it's a bit unclear. I realize you said "I'm trying to isolate… what exactly is the issue," but to get a helpful answer we might have to clarify it more! E.g. sometimes it seems like the focus is aural skills like maybe you're working on sight-singing or interval identification? And other times it seems like the focus is simply on performance accuracy, playing notes other than the one you mean to play.

It's also not clear how much the issue is related to learning new instruments, like you have lower accuracy on an instrument that is newer to you (that's to be expected!). Please use the "edit" button to try to explain more clearly exactly what you're experiencing.

Yeah it’s like you’ve written a bunch of good things about ear training and then asked how to solve the “issue”. What issue exactly?

Being in "a family of professional musicians" isn't a guarantee that your musical skills will be adequate. That said, I agree with Andy: it's really unclear what the problem is. Is your issue about "recognizing" intervals? Then there are many ways of hearing intervals and also many of recognizing them, as there are many ways of describing them. Or is it a problem about playing an interval? Then, how do you define it, and how is it clear to you? On what instrument? Or is it a problem about tuning? You mention string instruments, so it may be a playing technique problem. Please clarify.

I wonder if what you call a cheat is just a way to memorize a chunk of music. I suspect that is an optimization which allows you to remember more by encoding it more efficiently (by refering to the chunk instead of all its individual consituents). But I did not quite understand what you meant with the numbers.

Welcome. You've gone into a lot of detail, but not told us just what the problem is. First I'd turn to the more musical family members for personal advice.

Can you 100% nail the tune when singing it? ...Or is your memory of the tune also fuzzy?

I agree that it's unclear what you're trying to describe here. You write "I'm struggling to hear it"; what do you mean by "it"? You say that it's "a struggle to extrapolate to the general"; what do you mean by "the general"? You write that "I'm struggling to make progress"; what is it that you're trying to make progress with?

Start with common pop culture cliches. Learn 1,4,1,5; 6,4,1,5; etc. If you just sit and drill yourself on intervals with no context, you're going to struggle to overcome your problem. Use country music or something and learn those intervals. It's very simple. The other ones in between will get easier.
